# How to improve the build failure reporting of a prallel gradle build?

Tags: gradle

We use a parallel gradle build in our ci server. But finding the cause of the build failure is sometimes a pain, because one has to dig through the gradle output to find the real problem. I would like to improve that.

For example one of the gradle tasks uses `yarn`. If this task fails gradle reports the following in the jenkins console:

```
10:27:27  * What went wrong:
10:27:27  Execution failed for task ':foo-web:yarn'.
10:27:27  > Process 'command '/home/jenkins/workdir/workspace/foo/foo-web/.gradle/yarn/bin/yarn'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Then one has to scroll up a lot of lines to find the output of yarn due to parallel tasks being finished, just to find out yarn could not download a dependency.

Can we change the gradle build failure reporting so that it will append the error output of the failed task at the end of the build output to the failure report? Or is there some way to get gradles failure reporting and the output of the failed task more closely together?

Comment: Have you tried build scans? https://scans.gradle.com

Comment: @britter No, I would first need to get management approval for using this, and it doesn't seem likely that this will be granted easily.